# Determine if two html elements are siblings

Tags: python, html, lxml

So, I'm building a little utility to automatically grab text from any article-style page. My thought on how to best solve the problem was to find all elements with more than ~150 chars of text:

```
document.xpath("//*[string-length( text() ) > 150 ]")
```

I then get a list of elements back and I want to identify which of those elements are siblings, but if possible I'd like to avoid doing more DOM traversal for the sake of efficiency.

Is there some nice way of doing this in lxml?

Comment: I'm not sure where you're going with checking for ~150 characters of text...what does this indicate?  When comparing two elements to determine if they are siblings or not, why not just compare the parents of the elements?  If the parents are the same, then the elements are siblings.

Comment: @mittmemo it indicates that it's a block of text. Mostly because a parent check is slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given some list of nodes `l`, you could check whether parent of any pair of elements is the same (where the parent is obtained with `.getparent()`):

```
def get_siblings(l):
    for a in l:
        for b in l:
            if a < b: # this tests the elements' memory addresses, 
                      # so we don't get duplicate pairs or test 
                      # elements against themselves
                if a.getparent() == b.getparent():
                    yield (a, b)
```

Or maybe simpler:

```
def get_siblings(l):
    return ((a, b) for a in l
                   for b in l
                   if a < b
                   and a.getparent() == b.getparent())
```

You could also use a counter to find the parents with more than one sibling, and then find elements with those parents:

```
from collections import Counter
def get_siblings(l):
    c = Counter([x.getparent() for x in l])
    return [x for x in l if c[x.getparent()] > 1]
```

Comment: I think your last answer here is probably the right way to do this. Many thanks! I'm going to go ahead and remove my answer now since I think it doesn't have a lot of value over your last entry.

Comment: :) Sounds good. It did teach me about `Counter` though, that's very useful for doing this sort of thing!

Comment: Also note that if there are two groups of siblings, this solution won't distinguish between them. You could probably modify the code to identify the different groups if you wanted.

Comment: Probably, yea. Though luckily it's not required for this.